# Do animals regenerate health?

Tags: 7-days-to-die

Bears often fight against Zombies and early game it is a good way of taking bears out by attacking them after a fight against a horde. However, sometimes they fight during the night and I ask myself how or if they are regenerating any health after that. It would also be important to know at what rate, so if you have cancel a fight due to circumstances early game, how fast should you go back to continue to tickle him to death with your day one bow. Same applies to deers and pigs that you lost contact with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've performed some rudimentary tests on this -- I had a stag get trapped inside a walled-in area, so I knew he couldn't escape. I hit him several times with a bow (usually takes 3-4 "headshots" with a wooden bow in my experience) and waited nearby in my house a couple days. I came back and he was still there (surprised he didn't bleed out to be honest) and shot him once with the wooden bow in the body and he died.

TD;DR: It does not appear that the health of animals regenerate. I do know, however, if they live long enough to wander too far from you, the console will show them being removed from the game, and likely replaced with another animal at some random point. Damaging them and running off and later finding them is very unlikely.